# How to store JSON data in a variable in JavaSCript?

Tags: javascript, json, async-await, es6-promise

I need the function ** getJson () ** to fetch and return the data from json.

JSON (file.json):

```
    [
        {
                "01/01/2021":"Confraternização Universal",
                "15/02/2021":"Carnaval",
                "16/02/2021":"Carnaval",
                "02/04/2021":"Paixão de Cristo",
                "21/04/2021":"Tiradentes",
                "01/05/2021":"Dia do Trabalho",
                "03/06/2021":"Corpus Christi",
                "07/09/2021":"Independência do Brasil",
                "12/10/2021":"Nossa Sr.a Aparecida - Padroeira do Brasil",
                "02/11/2021":"Finados",
                "15/11/2021":"Proclamação da República",
                "25/12/2021":"Natal"
        }
]
```

1. I tried to use the async function but was unsuccessful.

Code:

```
async function getJson() {
    const response = await fetch('file.json');
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}
console.log(getJson());
```

Output:

```
Promise {<pending>}
```

2. It would also be useful if the data were stored in a variable, in ** obj ** for example. I tried the next code but it didn't work either.

Code:

```
var obj;
async function getJson() {
    const response = await fetch('file.json');
    obj = await response.json();
}
console.log(obj);
```

Output:

```
undefinded
```

Comment: try `console.log(await getJson())` in your first example and `await getJson(); console.log(obj)` in the second

Comment: Check my answer. That's is the main reason. Try it and do accept the answer and vote if this answer is helpful to you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `Async function` always returns a `Promise`. Use `.then()` block as shown below to get the data back:)

```
getJson().then(data=>console.log(data);
```

This function below is `async` and it will return a promise. When you were trying to `console.log(getJson())` a resolved promise is returned in your case. To get the value back from resolved promise we require `.then()` block and the callback has the data.

```
async function getJson() {
    const response = await fetch('file.json');
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}
getJson().then(data=>console.log(data));
```